# What is the purpose of Datetime.dateGmt() function?

Tags: datetime, date, timezone

In casual testing, I can see these give different results:

```
//assemble from component parts
Datetime now = System.now();
Date today = Date.newInstance(now.yearGmt(), now.monthGmt(), now.dayGmt());

//assemble from... something else!?
Datetime now = System.now();
Date today = now.dateGmt();
```

I thought I understood that `Date` has no concept of timezone. The same day is the same day everywhere. So, what is the purpose of `dateGmt` then? What use cases would suit each of the above code samples?

For the intention of writing to a `Date` field type in the database, I want to get the "true GMT date" from a `Datetime` instance. To do that, which technique is appropriate and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, I need to correct your question.  There is no `Date.DateGMT()` function; the `Date` class has no member `DateGMT`.  I believe you meant `DateTime.DateGMT`.

From [*Apex Code Developer's Guide*'s Primitive Data Types page](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_primitives.htm):

> **DateTime**: A value that indicates a particular day and time, such as a timestamp.
>
> **Date**: A value that indicates a particular day. Unlike Datetime values, Date values contain no information about time.

The important concept here is that a DateTime represents an exact moment in time, which has different representations in each timezone.  For example, as I type it is 11:56 AM on Feb 23 on my clock, as I am in the Eastern Standard timezone in the US.  However, it is currently 12:56 AM on Feb 24 in Shanghai, China (China Standard Time).  It is the same moment in time, but I've listed two representations of it, which have different Date portions.  Another representation is GMT, which is 4:56 PM on Feb 23.

Apex's DateTime object only exposes two representations of a moment in time:  The date & time in time zone of the context user, and the date & time in GMT.

So to answer the question "**What is the purpose of `DateTime.dateGmt()` function?**" - This function returns the Date component of the GMT representation of the exact moment in time represented by the DateTime.  In contrast, `DateTime.date()` returns the Date component of the context's user's timezone's representation of the DateTime.

In a comment on another answer showing an example of `date()` and `dateGMT()` returning different answers, you said, "I thought dates were timezone independent".  The apex `Date` object has no time component, and has no timezone component.  This is important - a `Date` object is just a month, day, and year, with no concept of time or timezone.  Consider some examples:

- If I say "Let's meet on May 1", the actual moment in time depends on what time I mean, which I didn't state.
- If I say "Let's meet at 10 AM on May 1", the actual moment in time depends on the timezone, which I didn't state.
- If I say "Let's meet in Sydney Australia at 10 AM AEDT on May 1", we've pinned down an exact moment in time.  The Date portion of the Local Time Zone (Australia Eastern Daylight Time) representation of that moment in time is May 1, 2015, but the Date portion of the GMT representation of that moment in time is Apr 30, 2015.

In your question, you provided two code samples:

```
//assemble from component parts
Datetime now = System.now();
Date today = Date.newInstance(now.yearGmt(), now.monthGmt(), now.dayGmt());

//extracted from existing datetime
Datetime now = System.now();
Date today = now.dateGmt();
```

There is no real difference here; both snippets will return the same Date value.  That's because `DateTime.yearGmt()` is the same as `DateTime.DateGmt().year()`, `DateTime.monthGmt()` is the same as `DatTime.DateGmt().month()`, etc.  Which method should you use?  Doesn't really matter, but the second one is shorter to read, more obvious in intent, and probably uses fewer cycles.

In your comment to another answer you asked, "I want to get the 'true GMT date' from a datetime instance... which technique is appropriate and why?"  Either approach will give you the correct Date for the GMT representation of the moment in time in your DateTime.  Just be sure that you are constructing the DateTime correctly.  If you are using System.now(), no worries.  but if you are using `Datetime.NewInstance(year, mo, day, hr, min, sec)`, keep in mind that the date and time values you provide will be treated as being in the context user's timezone.  If you mean to provide the date and time values as GMT, use `NewInstanceGMT`.

Comment: Was a pleasure digesting this Jason! Thank you indeed for your detailed thoughts and assessment. I feel this is really striving for preciseness and shaving away any little doubts and misnomers in the question and surrounding commentary. A much appreciated contribution to the mental model!

Answer (score 6):

[`dateGMT()`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_dayGmt) returns the date in the GMT timezone at the time of the Datetime.
This will provide the same answer for all user contexts and you should indicate this.

[`System.now()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_now) returns the time in GMT. Your Datetime fields in the database should also be in GMT.

`Date today = now.dateGmt()`; will give you the current date in GMT without conversion. It takes the date component from the now Datetime in GMT.

If you used `today = now.date()`, it would convert the now Datetime to the local timezone thus yielding the date for that timezone. NOTE: this local timezone is based on the context user.

I think `now.dateGmt()` is more concise and quickly recognizable, than your `Date.newInstance(now.yearGMT(), monthGMT(), dayGMT());`, but otherwise equivalent.

I have seen best practice is to load your data as `yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z` format to ensure salesforce uses the correct timezone. If not using GMT "Z", provide the timezone offset.

Regarding your observed differences, you are declaring the same variables multiple times, so I assume you tested your two approaches at different times. You should repeat your tests and see if they are still different. Try setting your user to GMT and compare, then change back to your local timezone.

Answer (score 3):

I think your assumption that date is same everywhere is not true. Date can be different at given moment.

When I run this code and i can see different dates:

```
Datetime now = System.now();

Date today = now.dateGmt();
System.debug('###' + today);
// >>>>>> 10:58:15:033 USER_DEBUG [4]|DEBUG|###2015-02-19 00:00:00
today = now.date();
System.debug('###' + today); 
// >>> 10:58:15:033 USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|###2015-02-18 00:00:00
```

To understand it better consider date as sequence of moments. GMT is standard and every time zone has its own offset with respect to GMT. So if offset is +1 hrs then you will see GMT date & your timezone date different from 12:00 am & 1:00am. Even when you ignore the time part of date time, it still stand true.

Comment: Oops, I thought dates were timezone independent. Say for the intention of writing to a `Date` field type in the database, I want to get the "true GMT date" from a datetime instance. Can you help me understand which technique is appropriate and why?

Answer (score 0):

In the programming world, dates and times are set to the computer that is computing that time stamp. The date() function should return the current time stamp of the server, where as dateGmt() will always return the time stamp in the standard GMT time zone.

This is useful when you need to know the specific time from a field, and you can trust that it's always in the same timezone, therefore the only logic you need to perform in the future when viewing that time stamp is to convert it to the end user's local timezone.